# Declare variable of different type foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm working with IMAP and POP3 mail in c# and I met a curious problem.
The uid (Unique ID) for the two type are different types: for the IMAP is long variable and for the POP is a string.
So, the function to download and save the mails are equal except for that.
I need to do a foreach loop but the only line that change is the first:

```
foreach (long uid in uids) //for the imap
foreach (string uid in uids) //for the pop
```

I can't declare uid first, so, there is a way to duplicate only this line but not the entire function?

Comment: Please show more context. What is that method doing with the uids?

Comment: Hi @DanielHilgarth, I need the uid to select one by one the mail and to create the folder that contains the uid in name (if the uid is "1" i will create the "C:\mail\1" folder).

Comment: Can you post where the uids list is populated for each POP and IMAP?

Comment: What is the type of `uids`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your statement of how you'll be using it:

```
foreach (object uid in uids)
{
    string uidStr = uid.ToString();
    // use uidStr, e.g.
    string myPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\mail\", uidStr);
```

Or:

```
foreach (string uid in uids.Select(x => x.ToString()))
```

Comment: By ten minute i will try this!

Comment: It works fine, thank you @TimS.! It is simple but I'm young and I still have many things to learn!;)

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
foreach (long uid in uids.OfType<long>())
foreach (string uid in uids.OfType<string>())
```

(But I don't have enough context from your question to give a more detailed answer.)

[EDIT]

If I take your meaning correctly, you could define your process method like so:

```
static void process(IEnumerable<string> uids)
{
    foreach (string uid in uids)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
process(uids.OfType<int>().Select(uid => uid.ToString()));
process(uids.OfType<string>());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) for this purpose:

```
foreach (dynamic uid in uids)
```

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't. "dynamic" is for *interoperating with legacy systems and dynamic languages*. Use the tool for its purpose.

Answer (score -1):

What happened to the use of var??

```
foreach (var uid in uids)
```

??
or have i completely misunderstood the question?